# Identify this tree please?

Tags: identification, trees

Let me know what to show, otherwise here is its flowers or seeds? In Australia

[image: A picture]

Comment: Resembles some kind of *Fraxinus*, which is not endemic for Australia. Maybe show the leaves and bark as well. And a picture of the whole tree might also be informative.

Comment: Maybe this is a jasmine